# compare multiplication of JSONObjects

Tags: android, compare, arrays

So, I have at this point a collections.sort of java values as you can see

and I have two keys that are integers (let's say for the sake of the example that  the values of tipo are 1,2 and the values of id are 3 and 4) and I want to sort the result of theyr multiplication:

Something like this:

valA = a.get(KEY_ONE)*a.get(KEY_TWO);
valB = b.get(KEY_ONE)*b.get(KEY_TWO);

Then compare them.

How can I do it??

here is the code that I have at this point.

```
Collections.sort( jsonValues, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

            private static final String KEY_ONE = "tipo";
            private static final String Key_TWO = "id";

            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
                String valA = new String();
                String valB = new String();

                try {

                    valA = (String) a.get(KEY_ONE.toString());
                    valB = (String) b.get(KEY_ONE.toString());

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    //do something
                }

                return valA.compareTo(valB);

            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            sortedJsonArray.put(jsonValues.get(i));
        }


        tvJson.setText(sortedJsonArray.toString());


    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Cast them to Integers if you are sure that they will only be Integers and then make your calculations! 
You can use: Integer.parseInt(string_value) and get the int value from string

Comment: I was really tired when I asked this question. 

The next day I've done that but with no sucess since the array was put in this order ( where the number = the rank of the multiplication - like if it was the smallest value of the multiplication of two keys then 1, if the second smallest 2, and so on ) 

3-4-5-6-7-1-2